# Meaning of "By her example"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase in bold?

> Through her courage, and **by her example**, she helped lay a
>   foundation that could live up to its creed. [Obama]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that this woman ("she") was a role model. She led by example or, in other words, set a good example for people to follow.